# How do i add a line break in PHP to seperate my form output from each other

Tags: php

i am completely new to PHP and as my degree for high school comes closer i decided to make an HTML form for our personal description in our yearbook. But as my PHP file handles the forms POST, i cannot figure out how to seperate the different input and it just outputs everything in one line. My PHP Code is this

```
<?php
$filename = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 6) . '.txt';
if ( !file_exists($filename) ) {
   //File put contents stuff here

   if(isset($_POST['fname']))
{
$data=$_POST['fname'];
$fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
}
if(isset($_POST['lname']))
{
$data=$_POST['lname'];
$fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
}
}


?>
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">
    <head>
        <title>Erstelle deinen Steckbrief</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="size=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="all">
   <header>
       <div id="ueberschrift">
        <h1>Erstelle deinen Steckbrief für die Abizeitung</h1>
        <p>Dies ist das Formular für das erstellen deiner Seite für die Abizeitung</p>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class="form">
        <form name="" method="post" action="upload.php">
            <label for="fname">Vorname:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="lname">Nachname:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="dateofbirth">Geburtsdatum:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="city">Wohnort:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="50"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="groupname">Gruppenname:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="groupname" id="groupname" size="50"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="futurejob">Späterer Berufswunsch:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="futurejob" id="futurejob" size="50"><br>            
            <br>
            <label for="bteacher">Lieblingslehrer/in:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="bteacher" id="bteacher" size="50"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="whatialwayswantedtosay">Was ich immer mal loswerden wollte:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="whatialwayswantedtosay" id="whatialwayswantedtosay" size="50"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="mymotto">Mein Lebensmotto:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="mymotto" id="mymotto" size="50"><br>            
            <br>
            <label for="bestlesson">Lieblingsfach:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="bestlesson" id="bestlesson" size="50"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="worstlesson">Hassfach:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="worstlesson" id="worstlesson" size="50"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="noschoolwithout">Ohne das hätte ich meine Schulzeit nicht geschafft:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="noschoolwithout" id="noschoolwithout" size="50"><br>
            <br>
            <label for="inthreewords">Meine Schulzeit in drei Worten:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="inthreewords" id="inthreewords" size="50"><br>            
            <br>
            <label for="myadvice">Mein Rat an jüngere Schüler:</label><br>
            <textarea name="myadvice" id="myadvice" cols="52" rows="5"></textarea>
            <br>
            <label for="ratingofconstruction">Anzahl Sterne des Baulärms 1-5:</label><br>
            <input type="number" name="ratingofconstruction" min="1" max="5" id="ratingofconstruction" size="1"><br>
            <br>
            Bild zum Hochladen wählen:
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <input type="submit" value="Abschicken" name="submit">   

            <label for=""></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Abschicken" name="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I will remove the Upload Picture code out of HTML because it doesnt seem to work either. It isnt even in the PHP file anymore.

Comment: You wish to add all POSTed fields and values to a textfile of random name - one entry per line?

Answer (score 3):

you can use for an instance `chr(10)`

```
$data=$_POST['fname'] . chr(10);
```

Comment: I also recommend @ProfesorAbronsius' answer as it's more complex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\n`, `PHP_EOL` or as already stated, `chr(10)` to give a new line to your text but IMO using `\n` is perhaps simplest when used with something like this:

```
<?php
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        $filename = substr( str_shuffle( "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ), 0, 6) . '.txt';
        
        if ( !file_exists( $filename ) ) {
            foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
                /*
                    `sprintf` can be used to create a formatted string where 
                    variables are substituted for certain placeholders.
                    
                    the `FILE_APPEND` flag ensures the file is written to
                    several times with previous data retained.
                */
                file_put_contents( $filename, sprintf( "%s: %s\n", $field, $value ), FILE_APPEND );
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Disclaimer:

Using `\n` within PHP string always make sure it's wrapped with double quotes like:

```
echo "Some text with new line at the end \n";
```

If you'll use it with single quote

```
echo 'Some text with new line at the end \n';
```

It will literally output with `\n` string at the end.

Comment: Kudos for turning it into a loop. I wonder if `fopen ... fwrite, fwrite, fwrite` is lighter than 3x `file_put_contents`. I'd just pool the data together and commit in one go to minimize disk access.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use `PHP_EOL` to add a line break.

```
<?php
$filename = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 6) . '.txt';
if ( !file_exists($filename) ) {
   //File put contents stuff here

   if(isset($_POST['fname']))
   {
      $data=$_POST['fname'];
      $fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
      fwrite($fp, $data);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['lname']))
   {
      $data=$_POST['lname'];
      $fp = fopen($filename, 'a');
      fwrite($fp, PHP_EOL . $data);
   }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, adding a `\n` newline character is what you're missing. *Professor Abronsius* made your life easier by turning your one-by-one writes into a loop. Don't do it one by one and repeat code, assuming you intend to save all the `$_POST` fields submitted!

There are also two other easy options to consider. First, saving as JSON:

```
$data = json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

This would give you a file with the following contents:

```
{
    "rname": "Arr Name",
    "fname": "Foo Name"
}
```

...and you could easily re-use the data later with the help of `json_decode()`.

If you really don't need the array keys, this is by far the simplest way to do it:

```
$data = implode("\n", $_POST);
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

No need to loop it, or to write each field to the file in a separate call. (In any case, you need to call `fopen` just once. Here we just use `file_put_contents` instead.) This method would give you a file with the following contents:

```
Arr Name
Foo Name
```

If you don't want to include all `$_POST` fields, you can filter your post data with:

```
$allowed = ['rname', 'fname'];
$fields = array_intersect_keys($_POST, array_fill_keys($allowed, ''));
```

Then, you'd use `$fields` as you'd use `$_POST`, implementing which-ever of these "bulk saving" methods best fits your use case.

**Caution:** On using bulk methods for user input commits. A malicious user might tweak the form/submitted data and add fields, and therefore white-listing fields -- specifying as above; or possibly by pulling them from your form definition, since they're already spelled out somewhere -- is recommended, if you intend to re-use the submitted data. You may also want to validate/sanitize the actual contents, but that's a topic for another day.

**P.S.** While we typically add `\n` as the newline character, this is the Linux & MacOS standard. Windows uses `\r\n`, and if you're doing this for a Windows context, you might want to use the native line endings instead. Any decent code editor, and also Notepad since 2018 ([ref](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/extended-eol-in-notepad/)), would work with either, but older software might act up and just fuse lines together.

**P.P.S.** A note on the use of `PHP_EOL` to produce a line-ending. Per the manual, `PHP_EOL (string): The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform.` Ie. `\n` or `\r\n` depending on your OS. Suppose you develop on Windows but later deploy to a Linux server, you might be better off just choosing one (`\n`) and sticking with it, to avoid data with mixed newline standards.